# Is it possible to determine the gender of visitor of my blogger.com blog?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, blogger, visitor-pattern

I would like to show slightly different content to male and female visitors, so I would like to know if there is a way to determine the gender of the visitor by JavaScript or any other method eg. an AJAX call from JavaScript to an external server which provide a backend to access the GData APIs with Python / Ruby, or simply accessing the cookie information. For example on YouTube there is a classification of the viewership by gender, so I think that Google services can determine the gender somehow, assuming that the visitor is logged in to his / her Google account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think that Google services can determine the gender somehow,
>   assuming that the visitor is logged in to his / her Google account.

Its possible for google because they have the cookie set in the browser and that cookie belong to a user who has entered the gender while creating a account (Gender is mandatory while creating gmail account). So its as simple as they go fetch the data from their database for the user gender.

If you have to use their API's to get the data you must atleast have their emailID and also your site must be google authentication enabled. Else its not possible.

Comment: Even so, the OP asks on how to integrate it on Blogger. Which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

They are able to do that because, as you said, `Google can somehow determine the gender, assuming the visitor is logged into his account`. Here you go, you have answered yourself.

Point being, when you create your account, you're asked for various details, from which there's a gender dropdown as well. That's how they know it.

Even if you would find a service like this ( you never will ), it would be impossible for you to show content based on their gender, as that's not an option into blogger's dashboard, and never will.

Comment: The difference of the content is only a clickable link in a blogger gadget ( I think HTML / Javascript gadget), not different posts for different genders.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Google Authentication System To Access User Gmail Account Information .

See https://developers.google.com

Comment: That's not an option. He's using `Blogger`. There is no option in Blogger that I'm aware of ( and pretty sure there will never be one ) to show various posts based on a user's gender.